# When we add a new dimension in existing cube,then full process the cube.Have any alternative to avoid cube full process?

Tags: ssas

I add a new dimension in my cube.Then all time full process the cube and get data.I want to avoid cube full process.have any alternative??
Please help me.

Kalyan

Comment: You can try processing the dimension and then processing only the measure groups related to the new dimension.